# Live Search Bar: how to update the data displayed in different component than the input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement a live search bar using Next.js. I am able to handle the input change, but I can't seem to filter my results based on the input.

layout.jsx:

```js
import './globals.css';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className='text-center bg-sky-800'>
        <h1 className='text-4xl mt-4 text-white'>My App</h1>
        <SearchBar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

SearchBar Component:

```js
'use client'
import { useState } from "react"


export default function SearchBar() {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    
    function handleChange(e) {
        setSearchInput(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <input 
        className="p-3 border rounded bg-blue-100"
        type="search" 
        placeholder="Search Robots"
        onChange={handleChange}
        />
    )
}
```

The component that holds the code for the items I want to filter (they are cards):

```
import Card from './Card'
import { robots } from './robots'

export default function RobotList() {
  return (
    <main>
      {robots.map(robot => {
          return (
            <Card key={robot.id} id={robot.id} name={robot.name} email={robot.email} />
          )
        })
      }
    </main>
  )
}
```

page.jsx:

```
import RobotList from './RobotList'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
        <RobotList />
    </main>
  )
}
```

The Card Component:

```
export default function Card({ id, name, email }) {
    return (
        <div className="text-center bg-green-300 p-3 rounded inline-block m-2 hover:scale-105 transition ease-in duration-300 drop-shadow-xl">
            <img src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200`} alt="robot" />
            <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm using Next.js `v13`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your current code, the component that's displaying the `robots` list is not tied to `input` at all. One way to implement the search, which won't change much the structure of your current components, is to transform `SearchBar` to a context provider that would return the filtred `robots`.

I called it `RobotsContextProvider`:

```js
// RobotsContextProvider.js

"use client";

// Make sure this is the correct path
import { robots } from "./robots";
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const RobotsContext = createContext();
export function useRobotsContext() {
  return useContext(RobotsContext);
}

export default function RobotsContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <RobotsContext.Provider
      value={{ robots: searchInput ? robots.filter((r) => r.name.includes(searchInput)) : robots }}
    >
      <input
        className="p-3 border rounded bg-blue-100"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search Robots"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {children}
    </RobotsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You wrap it around `children` in `RootLayout`:

```js
import "./globals.css";
import RobotsContextProvider from "./RobotsContextProvider";

export const metadata = {
  title: "My App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="text-center bg-sky-800">
        <h1 className="text-4xl mt-4 text-white">My App</h1>
        <RobotsContextProvider>{children}</RobotsContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In `RobotList`, you use `robots` from the context instead of importing it:

```js
"use client";

import Card from "./Card";
// Make sure this is the correct path
import { useRobotsContext } from "./RobotsContextProvider";

export default function RobotList() {
  const { robots } = useRobotsContext();
  return (
    <main>
      {robots.map((robot) => {
        return <Card key={robot.id} id={robot.id} name={robot.name} email={robot.email} />;
      })}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Make sure you read the comments.

Comment: Thanks so much @Youssouf, it works great! I will be sure to read up more on React contexts.